"Manage, Install, and Generate Color Profiles." Debian Partition Boot Up Stops at This Stage
As the title says, my Debian partition has had a problem for about two months, now, wherein I cannot properly boot my computer. It goes through the normal start-up process, and then hangs indefinitely when it reaches the stage "Manage, Install, and Generate Color Profiles."
After using Debian as my main OS for about five years now, I remain fairly ignorant of a lot of the finer details, so I apologize if I've left out some crucial detail in this description. As it stands, I genuinely can't think of anything else that seems relevant.

Hi, have you tried getting a live edition like Knoppix (https://knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)? Knoppix can be written on a CD, but it also has a script which will create a bootable system on a USB drive. Once you boot Knoppix from this USB drive, you should be able to chroot into the broken system, then please journalctl -xb to get the log of the latest boot attempt and provide the results here, so that we can help.

Thanks, I'll do that, and come back with the log.

You can use the same Debian installer you already have for the exact same purpose. @likewise Why Knoppix?

For what it's worth, I couldn't work out how to download Knoppix, anyway.

Worked it out and formatted a drive for it, but I have no idea how to boot from it.

Spent a few hours trying to boot from a few different USBs, tried formatting it in a few ways, none of them were properly recognized by the computer.

After saying that, and ONLY after saying that, it finally booted, but now I have no idea how to use it. A few seconds after it boots, the computer stops giving any signal to the monitor.

If you didn't install your Debian, better ask for help from who did it in the first place.

@ChanganAuto Knoppix is, to me at least, much simpler to use than Debian installer's rescue mode. Over the years always I've used Knoppix to resurrect a broken Debian system a few times. I did try Debian installer's rescue mode recently, but had to fall back to Knoppix anyway. It was my inexperience Debian installer for sure, but I like Knoppix because (1) it's install script creates persistent storage on the USB stick (so you can install additional tools and they stay between reboots) and (2) Knoppix is easier to use.

@H.Zable where does Knoppix boot die? Or have you had more luck with Debian installer's rescue mode? The bottom line is to get more information why your Debian installation fails to boot, it does not really matter whether you use Knoppix or anything else for it.

It dies less than a minute after starting. I've had more luck with Debian installer's, though I've yet to get the log.

Alright, there appear to be zero journal entries

Upon further inspection, there are some, though the specific command you provided isn't recognized by Debian. I haven't been able to figure out how to narrow down my search results, though; the only command that gets results provides everything going back three months, which would be impractical to sift through manually
